# Simplify the lua "LookAt" function

Tags: math, vector, lua

folks!

I have a working function named "LookAt" written in Lua language.

There is no mistakes in code and logic of this function.

But i believe we can simplify the math logic.

```
function LookAt(target)
  local origin = Vec3.New(Engine.ClientData.Origin) 
  local direction = origin - target

  Engine.Pitch = math.deg(math.atan(direction.Z, math.sqrt((direction.X ^ 2) + (direction.Y ^ 2))))
  Engine.Yaw = math.deg(math.atan(direction.Y, direction.X)) - 180.0
end
```

Comment: `Engine.Yaw = math.deg(math.atan(-direction.Y, -direction.X))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much you can do to *simplify* the math logic. There's very little redundancy here you can take advantage of. But you can factor it into pieces like this:

```
function atan_deg(y, x)
  return (math.deg(math.atan(y, x)))
end

function hypotenuse(x, y)
  return (math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2))
end

function LookAt(target)
  local origin = Vec3.New(Engine.ClientData.Origin) 
  local direction = origin - target
  local X, Y, Z = direction.X, direction.Y, direction.Z

  Engine.Pitch = atan_deg(Z, hypotenuse(X, Y))
  Engine.Yaw = atan_deg(Y, X) - 180.0
end
```